# Como gerar diversos ZIPs dinamicamente em memória, com Python?

Tags: python, xml, dataframe, arquivo-zip

Estou lendo um dataframe em Python, e pra cada linha do mesmo, preciso salvar a coluna que contém um XML em um arquivo, em memória, para posteriormente zipar estes arquivos. Até aí tudo bem. A questão é que eu preciso gerar estes ZIPs dinamicamente, de acordo com uma determinada chave presente dentro dos arquivos. Se a chave for igual à anterior, deve gravar o XML no mesmo diretório. Caso contrário, deverá gerar um zip diferente para essa nova chave. Todos os arquivos com a mesma chave devem ficar juntos. Ou seja, caso existam 20 chaves diferentes, preciso gerar 20 ZIPs diferentes.

Abaixo, segue o código até o momento:

```
.
.
.
arrayKeys = []
memoryZip = BytesIO()
memoryXml = StringIO()
today = datetime.today()
todaysYear = str(today.year)
todaysMonth = str(today.month)
todaysDay = str(today.day)
todaysHour = str(today.hour)
todaysMinute = str(today.minute)
todaysSecond = str(today.second)

for line in range(len(dataFrame)):
.
.
.
    # Busca a chave:
    key = str(dataFrame['KEY'][line])
    directory = 'key='+key

    # Se a nova chave já existir na lista, deve gravar os dados no mesmo zip:
    if key in arrayKeys:            
        with zipfile.ZipFile(memoryZip, 'w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, compresslevel=9) as zf:            

            # Cria a estrutura de pastas:        
            path = 'folder1\\folder2\\'+directory+'\\xml'+line+'.xml'

            # Salva os arquivos na estrutura necessária
            dataFrame.iloc[line,:].to_csv(memoryXml, header=False, index=False, escapechar='\\', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)            
            zf.writestr(path, memoryXml.getvalue())

            # Nome do zip:
            zipName = key+'_'+todaysYear+todaysMonth+todaysDay+todaysHour+todaysMinute+todaysSecond

    # Se não, deve gravar em outro zip 
    else:
        arrayKey.append(directory)

        # Gerar outro zip dinamicamente, para cada chave
        with zipfile.ZipFile(memoryZip, 'w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, compresslevel=9) as newZf:

            # Cria a estrutura de pastas em memória:        
            path = 'diretorio\\'+key+'\\xml'+line+'.xml'

            # Salva os arquivos na estrutura necessária
            dataFrame.iloc[line,:].to_csv(memoryXml, header=False, index=False, escapechar='\\', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)            
            newZf.writestr(path, memoryXml.getvalue())

            # Nome do zip:
            zipName = key+'_'+todaysYear+todaysMonth+todaysDay+todaysHour+todaysMinute+todaysSecond

# Função que faz o upload dos zips (a implementação dela é irrelevante, nesse caso)
# Aqui, preciso que sejam enviados todos os zips em memória
upload('storage', memoryZip.getvalue(), f'{zipName}.zip')
```

Comment: O problema está descrito inclusive no título da pergunta.

Comment: Qual é a mensagem de erro gerada?

Comment: Timeout. Não sei se é pelo fato dele percorrer todas as tags de todos os XMLs.

Comment: Não seria mais interessante criar um RAM Disk, salvar esses zips dentro desse RAM Disk e passar para a função a referência desse RAM Disk com os arquivos ZIP salvos?

Answer (score 0):

Problema solucionado: basicamente, foi necessário abrir apenas um ZipFile (ao invés de 2, como mostrado acima) em memória, e ir salvando os arquivos de acordo com a chave. Após o laço, o ponteiro de memória da variável memoryXml foi setado pra 0 (memory.seek(0)) e depois truncado (memoryXml.truncate(0)).